# Dynamically creating ArrayList inside a loop

Tags: java, arraylist

How do we create arraylist dynamically inside a loop?

something like -

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)  
{  
List<Integer> arr(i) = new ArrayList<>();  
}
```

Comment: Means you need to create 4 arraylist and return an array containing reference to all that arraylists??

Comment: yes, i want to create four arraylist

Comment: I appreciate this question, I have faced serious need for this in competitive programming contests.

Answer (score 16):

It sounds like what you *actually* want is a list of lists:

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    lists.add(list);
    // Use the list further...
}

// Now you can use lists.get(0) etc to get at each list
```

EDIT: Array example removed, as of course arrays of generic types are broken in Java :(

Comment: That works fine, Thank you:)  And can you tell me how do i access individual arraylist and add elements to it?

Comment: @Preethi: See the comment below the loop.

Answer (score 3):

**Creating a list of Arraylist:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i=0;

    Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);

    List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of lists");
    int n=obj.nextInt();

    while (i<n) {
      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      System.out.println("Enter the number of integers you want to enter in an ArrayList");

      int d=obj.nextInt();
      for(int j=0;j<d;j++){
        list.add(obj.nextInt());
      }
      lists.add(list);
      System.out.println("List "+i+ "is created");
      System.out.println(lists.get(i));
      System.out.println("");
      i++;
    } //end of while

  } //end of main
} //end of class
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want something like this. This will be creating a number of "List" as much as you want. In this case, I am creating two Lists:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class NumberOfList {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        List<Integer> list[];
        list = new LinkedList[2];
        for(int x=0; x<2; x++){ 
            list[x]= new LinkedList(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
List<List<Integer>> dataList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
 List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 dataList.add(tempList);
}
```

For adding data

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
int value = 5+i;
  dataList.get(i - 1).add(value);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an ArrayList having an ArrayList as it's elements.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mainArrayList = 
new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

you can add elements into mainArrayList by:

```
ArrayList<Integer> subArrayList;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {

    subArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    subArrayList.add(1); // I'm adding a random value to subArrayList
    mainArrayList.add(subArrayList);

}
```

Now, the mainArrayList will have the 4 arrayLists that we added and we can access
each element(which are ArrayLists) using for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<Integer>> dataList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for(i=0;i<4;i++)  
{  
 List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();  

 dataList .add(arr );
}
```

This might help you. If not, please clarify the scenario.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure what you mean, maybe this?

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
for(i=0;i<4;i++)  
{  
    arr.add(i);  
}
```

Comment: You are adding i values ie 1,2,3,4 into arraylist. This is not what OP wants

Comment: It's hard to say what author means originally, right? =) Just my guess.